# Using Apollo with Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, apollo

I'm new to Android development and I'm starting a new personal project where I have to fetch data from a backend server using GraphQL queries.

The question is how to implement data persistence using Room Database with Apollo auto-generated classes.

I thought of creating my own model class which is separate from Apollo Auto-generated classes and put the response as soon as it comes to an object of the model which I created and use it as the main source of data which will be displayed to the user.

Is this a good approach? if so what is the best practice to map apollo responses to my model object. 
Currently, I'm using a for loop which iterates through the response and maps every field to the corresponding field and inserts it in a list. Is this efficient?

Comment: 1 year old question, did u find out what is the pest practice in this case?

Comment: Yes. I ended up using MVVM with clean architecture. The data classes which are auto generated by Apollo are only used as a DTO. When I get the response from the back-end, I map it to an object which gets used by the view layer.